# Dead simple web interface to manage files on a server?

Tags: gratis, web-apps, web-development

I need a dead simple interface to upload, download and manage files on a particular directory on my server (`/upload` in my case). It should also:

- preferably not require authentication and/or setting up permissions
- have as few dependencies as possible
- moving/copying/searching files would be nice to have but not at all necessary
- be free (at least as in beer) and, additionally open-source

Comment: What does your server has? Rails? PHP? what version? For installation, do you have SSH root access to it, or only FTP access? Do you need an authentication mechanism, or will you do it yourself with .htaccess or similar? Do you want multi-user? Do you want different rights for each user?

Answer (score 1):

I have build something like that myself a few month ago.

I used a simple HTML5 Upload script (Javascript) : [DropZone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)

And a php file manager in the upload dir : [simple File Manager](http://onedotoh.sourceforge.net/)

This is working pretty well.. I also added a little extra "remote upload" field.

You can Customize it and if you have experience with html/php it can be setup within minutes.